# Preventing a never ending while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have the following code which checks a file being imported and I want to count the number of lines of data it has so I can assign them to an array.  But the loop just keeps running and does not stop at the 8 lines of data I have.

This is the code I have for the count that keeps looping:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("src/data/VinylRecords.txt"));
int lines = 0;
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    lines += 1;
}
System.out.println("number of lines " + lines);
```

I am very new to Java but have used while loops before ok and cannot see what is wrong with this?  Please can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: `hasNextLine()` doesn't _consume_ any input.

Comment: you need to go to the next line like `in.nextLine()`

Comment: You need to move control to next line by using ```in.nextLine()```. What you are doing will just keep reading the first line over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The hasNextLine() is a method of Java Scanner class which is used to check if there is another line in the input of this scanner. It returns true if it finds another line, otherwise returns false" https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-hasnextline-method
but it does not change the scanner value.
you need to add .nextLine()